# how do i add all the given conditions into one or two loops?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement

so I was given this problem to do at home and instructed to only use loops.

Write a method double calcFutureSalary(double curretSalary, int year) that takes an initial salary of a person, a number of year. The method will calculate the salary after a certain number of years. If a worker works less than 3 years, the salary increase 3% each year. If a worker works equal more than 3 years but less than 10 years, the salary increase 5% each year. And if a worker works equal or more than 10 years. The salary increase 8% each year.

For example, if you want to check the salary after 12 years. The first 2 year the salary will be increased by 3%, then for year 3 to year 9, the salary increase 5%, and for year 10 to year 12, the salary increase 8%.

The thing is, I only know how to do a part of it. for example:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= year; i++) {
        currentSalary *= 1.03;
    }
        return currentSalary;
```

my Problem is I don't know how to apply the other conditions using loops afterwards. HELP PLEASE.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, please refer to the below two links.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= year && i<=2 ; i++) {
        currentSalary *= 1.03;
    }
for (int i=3 ; i<= year && i<=9 ; i++)
And so on...
return currentSalary;
```

You can also make it less prone to bugs by not repeating yourself.

```
int i = 1;    
for(; i <= year && i<=2 ; i++) {
            currentSalary *= 1.03;
        }
for (; i<= year && i<=9 ; i++)
And so on...
return currentSalary;
```

You can also use one single loop like this:

```
const int numIntervals = 3;
const int yearIntervals[] = {1,3,10,10000};
const float factors[] = {1.03f,1.05f,1.08f};
for ( int interval = 0 ; interval < numIntervals ; interval++ )
{
  for ( int y = yearIntervals[interval]; y < yearIntervals[interval+1] && y<=year; y++ )
  {
    currentSalary *= factors[interval];
  }
}
return currentSalary;
```

Comment: @TheFlash you're welcome. Please like and accept the answer if it's the answer you were looking for.